# Why does new select form increase?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
 @post.post_tags.build
```

the above is posts contorller(post_tags is intermediate table between posts and tags) and view is like this.

```
    <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.fields_for :post_tags do |pt| %>
        <%= pt.select :tag_id, @tags.map{|t| [t.name, t.id]}, { :prompt => "choose name", label: "tag" }, class: "tag-fields" %>
      <% end %>
    </div>
```

When I edit a post, tags related to the post show correctly but new select box with "choose name" is also created. I don't want the new select box and I don't know why select box is created.

How should I fix it?

Thanks,
Ken

Answer (score 0):

When using indirect relationships don't focus on the joining models. ActiveRecord will create them for you.

Lets say you have:

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :tags, through: :taggings
end

class Tag < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :posts, through: :taggings
end

class Tagging < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :tag
  belongs_to :post
end
```

This will let us tag a post by:

```
@post.tags < @tag
```

Or create a tag by:

```
@post.tags.create(name: '#yolo')
```

If you want to create a select tag or checkboxes where a user can choose tags use the [collection helpers](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-collection_check_boxes):

```
<%= form_for(:post) do |f| %>
  <%= f.collection_check_boxes :tag_ids, Tag.all, :id, :name %>
<% end %>
```

The special `relation_name_ids` setters can create/destroy associations on the fly from an array of ids. The best thing is that Rails will handle joining for you when you use HABTM or `has_many through:`.

Comment: `fields_for` is used when you want to create nested records - not to select from a collection.